# Java application running slow on one system but very fast on the other?

Tags: java, performance, file

There was some file operation application required to process large files. I created a jar file for the same. I tested the application on my system for 1GB file it processed in 3 minutes but same jar when executed on different system for same file, it took 40 minutes.I thought it might be due java heap memory, but when I execute jar on my system with same java heap space it again got executed in less than 5 minutes.

Any help will be appreciated. Please comment if any more information is required.

Configuration for my system:
RAM: 8GB
Java version: 7
VM -XMS128m -Xmx256m
OS: Windows 7

Configuration for test system:
RAM: 6GB
Java version: 7
VM -Xms128m -Xmx256m
OS: Windows 7

Comment: Can't expect the same speeds on different machines. Different CPUs performs at different rates

Comment: Also possible differences in disks. Maybe the difference in RAM matters. We sure don't know the details of your equipment.

Comment: Thanks for your response Vince, but the difference is very high 5 mins and 40 minutes.

Comment: **How** are you accessing the file? And what is the load average on the second machine?

Comment: Has one computer a ssd?

Comment: Can you put some log or break points to find which lines or functions take more time ?! Also may be you have some hard disk issue, for example `bad sector`, try to copy the file on another hard, or external hard disk to see the result

Comment: No mh-dev, none of them have SSD.

Comment: Its depends on many thing  SSD, How many cores

Comment: If you run the program again on the second system, is it fast?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am reading file using BufferedReader. I don't know how to calculate load average. Could you please share a link to calculate the same.

Comment: The load average is reported by Windows performance tools.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few possible explanations:

- Different file systems.  For example, if the test system was storing the file on a network share, and either the file server or the network was slow / overloaded, then you could get slow reads.
- Virtualization.  If the test system was a VM, and there was a lot of contention for I/O between VMs on the same hypervisor, you could see slow reads.
- Memory contention.  If the application mapped the file into memory, then on a system where there was physical RAM starvation you could get really slow I/O compared to system where this wasn't the case.  (To determine if this is the case you need to look at what else is happening on the test system.)
- On some operating systems, antivirus products can have a significant performance impact.
- It is possible that there is a hardware fault in the test system.

A lot of these things can be diagnosed by looking at system level performance stats.  Using a Java profiler (on both systems) could also help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with it too, and i figured out that's because of AV, just turn it off. Im using avast. hope it helps !